# Call C# functions from Tcl

Tags: c#, .net, tcl, wrapper

I want to integrate Tcl shell to my .NET application. Once I used SWIG for doing the same for C++ application, but SWIG doesn't generate wrappers for C# code. Is there any tool for that? If no does anybody have an example of how to do this manually with Tcl API? Translating it from C++ is pretty much difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to look at [Eagle](http://eagle.to/). What's more, the developer of Eagle is *the* expert on intermingling Tcl and the .NET CLR.